# ways to implement a rand/srand? c++

Tags: c++, project

How can i insert a rand / srand into the code to make it ask the questions in a random order? 
I am not very familiar with the rand and srand. What i need is a srand and/or rand into a switch-case but cannot understand how to make it work.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <string>
    #include <ctime>
    using namespace std;
    struct highscore{
    int svar;
    };


    int main(){
        ofstream highscore;            
bool fail = true;
int lost, fraga, svar = 0; // these are for the Start option
int fraga2; // for srand / rand 
int load ,loadh, loadg, tillbaka; // these are for the loading option
string line; // also loading option
char val;

do{
    cout << " Menu" << endl;
    cout << " 1. Start" << endl;
    cout << " 2. Load" << endl;
    cout << " 3. Credits" << endl;
    cin >> val;
    switch(val){

          case '1':

                  highscore.open("Highscore.txt", ios::app);
                  if (!highscore){
                  cout << "file could not open";
                  exit (1);
                  }
                  srand(fraga2(time(0));
                  for (int fraga = 0; fraga< 500; fraga++){
                     cout << "WELCOME TO THE CISCO QUIZ  GOOD LUCK" << endl;
                     cout << "how many layers are there in the OSI model?" << endl;
                     cout << "1. 4" << endl;
                     cout << "2. 5" << endl;
                     cout << "3. 7" << endl;
                     cin >> fraga;
                     switch(fraga){
                                  case 1:

                                       cout << "Game Over!" << endl;
                                       cout << "Do you wish to restart? (answer with 1 for yes and 2 for no)" << endl;
                                       cin >> lost;
                                       if(lost == 2 ){
                                               fail = false;
                                               }
                                       break;

                                  case 2:

                                       cout << "Game Over!" << endl;
                                       cout << "Do you wish to restart? (answer with 1 for yes, 2 for no)" << endl;
                                       cin >> lost;
                                       if(lost == 2 ){
                                               fail = false;
                                               }
                                       break;

                                  case 3:
                                       svar = svar + 5;
                                       fraga = fraga + 1;
                                       break;
                                  default:
                                    cout << "error" << endl;
                                       }

                                       if(svar == 5){
                                          cout << "what is the full name of OSPF?" << endl;
                                          cout << "1. Open Shortest Path First" << endl;
                                          cout << "2. Online Shooting Pro Fishing" << endl;
                                          cout << "3. On Short Path First" << endl;
                                          cin >> fraga;
                                          switch(fraga){

                                                          case 1:
                                                          svar = svar + 5;
                                                          fraga = fraga +1; 
                                                               break;                                                                             

                                                          case 2:
                                                               cout << "Game Over!"<< endl;
                                                               cout << "Do you wish to restart? (answer with 1 for yes, 2 for no)" << endl;
                                                               cin >> lost;
                                                               if(lost == 2 ){
                                                                  fail = false;
                                                                  }
                                                               break;


                                                          case 3:
                                                               cout << "Game Over!" << endl;
                                                               cout << "Do you wish to restart? (answer with 1 for yes, 2 for no)" << endl;
                                                               cin >> lost;
                                                               if(lost == 2 ){
                                                                  fail = false;
                                                                 }
                                                                 }
                                                                 }          
                     if(svar == 10){
                     cout << "What does TTL mean?" << endl;
                     cout << "1. Twin Twitched Life" << endl;
                     cout << "2. Two Time Lives" << endl;
                     cout << "3. Time To Live" << endl;
                     cin >> fraga;                                  
                       switch(fraga){
                         case 1:
                          cout << "Game Over!" << endl;
                          cout << "Do you wish to restart? (answer with yes, YES or Yes)"<< endl;
                          cin >> lost;
                                  if(lost == 2 ){
                                     fail = false;
                                       }
                         break;


                       case 2:
                         cout << "Game Over!" << endl;
                         cout << "Do you wish to restart? (answer with 1 for yes and 2 for no)" << endl;
                         cin >> lost;
                            if(lost == 2 ){
                                 fail = false;
                                     }
                       break;


                       case 3:
                       svar = svar + 10;
                       fraga = fraga +1; 
                       break;
                       }
                       }
                      if(svar == 20){
                              cout << "What is the first command you enter on a Cisco router?" << endl;
                              cout << " 1. enable"<< endl;
                              cout << " 2. disable" << endl;
                              cout << " 3. enter" << endl;
                              cin >> fraga;

                              switch(fraga){
                                            case 1:
                                                 svar = svar + 5;
                                                 fraga = fraga +1; 
                                                 break;

                                            case 2:
                                                 cout << "Game Over!" << endl;
                                                 cout << "Do you wish to restart? (answer with 1 for yes and 2 for no)" << endl;
                                                 cin >> lost;
                                                  if(lost == 2 ){
                                                       fail = false;
                                                               }
                                                 break;
                                            case 3:
                                                 cout << "Game Over!" << endl;
                                                 cout << "Do you wish to restart? (answer with 1 for yes and 2 for no)" << endl;
                                                 cin >> lost;
                                                  if(lost == 2 ){
                                                     fail = false;
                                                                }
                                                 break;
                                                 }                                         
                                                 }
                                                 cout << svar;
                                  if(svar == 25){
                                          cout << "which protocol is the most prefered?" << endl;
                                          cout << " 1. RIP" << endl;
                                          cout << " 2. EGRP" << endl;
                                          cout << " 3. EIGRP" << endl;
                                          cin >> fraga;
                                          switch(fraga){
                                                        case 1:
                                                               cout << "Game Over!" << endl;
                                                               cout << "Do you wish to restart? (answer with 1 for yes and 2 for no)" << endl;
                                                               cin >> lost;
                                                                   if(lost == 2 ){
                                                                       fail = false;
                                                                                 }
                                                               break;


                                                         case 2:
                                                              cout << "Game Over!"<< endl;
                                                              cout << "Do you wish to restart? (answer with 1 for yes and 2 for no)" << endl;
                                                              cin >> lost;
                                                               if(lost == 2 ){
                                                                    fail = false;
                                                                             }
                                                                break;


                                                        case 3:
                                                             svar = svar + 15;
                                                             fraga = fraga +1; 
                                                             cout << "You have completed the game press 1 to exit or if you wish to do it again or check highscores press 2" << endl;
                                                             cin >> lost;
                                                             if (lost == 1 ){
                                                                      fail = false;
                                                                      }
                                                             else{
                                                                  fail = true;
                                                                  }
                                                             break;
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                 }                                                           
                                              highscore <<"Score: " << svar << '\n';                
                                          highscore.close(); 
                                          cin.ignore(10,'\n');

                                          cin.get();

     case '2':
        cout << "type 1 to load game or type 2 to load highscores" << endl;
        cin >> load;
        if (load == 1){
                 cout << "in progress";
                 }
        else if(load == 2){
             ifstream loadh ("highscore.txt");
             if (loadh.is_open())
             {
              while ( loadh.good() )
              {
               getline (loadh,line);
                       cout << line << endl;
                   }
                   cout << "do you wish to return to the menu press 1 else press any number" << endl;
                   if (tillbaka != 1){
                                fail = false;
                                }

                highscore.close();
                               }
             }
             cin.ignore(10,'\n');

cin.get();
        break;

    case '3':
        cout << "made by trickjay the most awesome guy on the planet!!!" << endl;
        cin.ignore(10,'\n');

       cin.get();
        break;



     }

    }while(fail);
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps you should be reading the documentation of these functions if you don't know what they do.

Comment: Start by reading the manual.

Comment: And after reading the manual, make a small program that shows what you are trying to achieve.  Then, incorporate that in your code.  Come back if you have specific questions about the small program.

Comment: The standard library **implements** `rand` and `srand`. Your program would **use** them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked those functions in references? They are pretty well described and there are also some examples. You should always start with that before trying to 'google' for the answer.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/srand

Comment: thanks i will look it up was on there before might've missed that thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
// Returns 100% guaranted random number based on timestamp
int randNumber() {
    return 213213;
}
```

You can also implement it like

```
// This works too
int randNumber() {
    return rand();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int num;
for( int i=0; i<3 ; i++ ) {
    num = rand() % 3;
    switch(num) {
    case 0: askone(); break;
    case 1: asktwo(); break;
    case 2: askthree(); break;
    }
}
```

This will give the same order every program run. Check out seeding if you want something less deterministic. Also you may want to add some mechanism to avoid duplicate questions.

Unrelated, you should look into reducing indentation in your program. By putting some sub-tasks into functions for example.

Also, you can change the outer do-while loop to a normal while loop without changing your programs behavior. It will make your code clearer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a compiler that supports C++11 then you have the new [`random`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) methods:

```
std::random_device rd;

std::mt19937 e2(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, 2);

int num;
for( int i=0; i<3 ; i++ ) {
  num = dist(e2);
  switch(num) {
  case 0: askone(); break;
  case 1: asktwo(); break;
  case 2: askthree(); break;
  }
}
```

For this case it may not make a big difference but in the long term there are advantages to not using [`std::rand`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand) since it is not thread safe and the quality of the random sequence generated by `rand` is not guaranteed.